# how get all row change crud in jqgrid with btn click

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

hi iam use  free jqGrid 4.15.1

i want btn click  get all change rows for exmaple
 3 row edit
 2 row insert
 1 row deleted 
iam use this code i want tish result insert this row

i insert new  this tree row

```
{ id: "gridad", Name: "Name 4", PackageCode: "83123a", other: "x",> },
  { id: "gridadd", Name: "Name 5", PackageCode: "834",  other: "x", > },
  { id: "gridadd", Name: "Name 6", PackageCode: "83566a", other: "z",  }
```

edit this row

```
>  { id: "10", Name: "Name 122", PackageCode: "83566a1000", other: "z", 
> }
```

delete this row

```
> { id: "20", Name: "Name 3", PackageCode: "83432a", other: "y"},
```

this my code

```
 $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var data = [
                { id: "10", Name: "Name 1", PackageCode: "83123a", other: "x", subobject: { x: "a", y: "b", z: [1, 2, 3]} },
                { id: "20", Name: "Name 3", PackageCode: "83432a", other: "y", subobject: { x: "c", y: "d", z: [4, 5, 6]} },
                { id: "30", Name: "Name 2", PackageCode: "83566a", other: "z", subobject: { x: "e", y: "f", z: [7, 8, 9]} }

            ],

            $grid = $("#packages");

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: data,
            datatype: "local",
            colModel: [
                { name: "PackageCode", width: 110 },
                { name: "Name", width: 300 }
            ],
            pager: "#packagePager",
            rowNum: 2,
            rowList: [1, 2, 10],
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            caption: "Packages",
            height: "auto",
            sortname: "Name",
            autoencode: true,
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
                  });
        $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#packagePager",
            { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {},
            { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true });
        $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn", stringResult: true });
    });
```

this button for get all change

```
$("#customerCodesTableSave").click(function () {
        var gridData = myGrid.jqGrid('getRowData');

        var postData = JSON.stringify(rowdata);
        alert(gridData.length);
        alert(postData);
        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            alert(i + "_" + (gridData[i]['id']));

            if (gridData[i].id == $(myGrid)[0].id + "_0")
            {
                alert(gridData[i]['id']);
            }
            //myGrid.jqGrid('saveRow', gridData[i]['id']);

        }

     saveGrid();

    });
```

Comment: First of all I fixed the tags used in your question. Please read the descriptions of tags here [mvcjqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvcjqgrid/info) and [free-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info). It's unclear which editing mode you plan to use. Depend on the editing mode chosen one can use the corresponding callbacks to increment the counter of inserted, deleted and edited rows. I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/20/ based on your code. You can extend it by including editing, which you need.

Comment: thanks update this demo

Comment: You are welcome! Which editing mode you plan to use?

Comment: iam mode inline .i want show change rows  then update or insert when btn click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example `aftersavefunc` callback of inline editing and `afterComplete` of row deleting to collect the statistic of added, edited and deleted rows. You can hold the statistic in a custom option of jqGrid.

The demo [update demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/72/)

```
stat: { // custom option to hold the editing statistics
    edit: 0,
    add: 0,
    del: 0
},
formDeleting: {
    afterComplete: function (jqXHR, postdata) {
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
        p.stat.del++;
    }
},
inlineEditing: {
    aftersavefunc: function (rowid, jqXhr, postData, options) {
        // postData.oper will be either "add" or "edit"
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
        p.stat[postData.oper]++;
    }
}
```

You can get the statistics in the same way like you access to other jqGrid parameters:

```
$("#getStat").click(function () {
    var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    alert("added rows: " + p.stat.add + "\n" +
          "edited rows: " + p.stat.edit + "\n" +
          "deleted rows: " + p.stat.del);
});
```

Of cause the above code is very simple. You can hold the array with rowids of editing/added and deleted rows instead of just numbers. It will allows you to hold more exact statistic. I mean that the simplest code above will increment `stat.edit` if the user will edit *the same* row multiple times. If the added/edited row will be deleted later then the `stat.add` and `stat.edit` will be not adjusted. Holding array of rowids in `stat.add`, `stat.edit` and `stat.del` will allow to fix hold more exact statistics.

Comment: thanks but iam need row arrye dont count crud.iam need row is add :1 add: pacgecode:10, name :oleg

Comment: @saeed3164: Sorry, but I don't understand where you have any problem. You have full information about inserted/edited row in `aftersavefunc` and deleted row in `afterComplete` (see the parameters of the callbacks). You need just change the implementation of `aftersavefunc` and `afterComplete` based on your requirements.

Comment: thanks my friend: I have value  rows either edited or deleted or add

Comment: @saeed3164: I still not sure, where you have a problem. For example, `aftersavefunc` callback has `rowid` parameter. Thus you can use `$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid)` to get the result of editing. If you need to have information about deteting row then you need use `beforeSubmit` instead of `afterComplete`: https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/43/

Comment: thanks is correct but when btn click 'Display Editing Statistics' show rows changed no when add for per row.Show all the changes together

Comment: @saeed3164: Could you formulate more detailed what you mean. 'Display Editing Statistics' can display *any information*, which you need, but I have no idea what you need. You can **collect** any information, because of existence many callbacks. If the user click on 'Display Editing Statistics' you can display the information, which you previously collected.

Comment: i want when click btn show display  info when add or del or edit

Comment: @saeed3164: I can't follow you. What is your question? What you can't implement yourself? Where I can help you?

Comment: :iam update this sample :https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/70/  but iam need deleted rows and at the end  all changes push arrye

Comment: @saeed3164: You can see in the demo `formDeleting` and `inlineEditing` options. The options defines *default options* used by form delete and inline editing. I displayed the value `rowData` with respect of `alert(JSON.stringify(rowData));` to show that `rowData` contains information which you need. Thus you need just replace `alert(JSON.stringify(rowData));` to push in some array. You can use the array inside of click event handler. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/72/ an example. I recommend you additionally use `inlineNavOptions` options instead of parameters of `inlineNav`

Comment: thnaks your answer is the solution.only one question. is possible change value rowData.rowid  is rowid=10 iam chnage  id deleted rowid ='del_10' than puhs

Comment: @saeed3164: I'm not sure, but I hope, that I understand you. You can make **copy** of the row data using `$.extend(true, {}, rowData)`, make any changes in the copy and place the copy in the array, which you will use later. See modified `beforeSubmit` function of `formDeleting` in https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/73/